# How to publish a vue js plugin that modifies an existing plugin

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a plugin that utilizes components from another Vuejs plugin (Vuetify).  Basically, I have some common components I want to share across multiple applications with our company.

I thought it would just be a matter of:

1. Create a github repo for the shared components
2. Author the plugin
3. Reference the repo in consuming apps via `npm install`

Here is the gist of the plugin:

```
// src/index.js <-- package.json/main is set to "src"
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";
import * as api from "./api";

export default function install(Vue) {
    Vue.component("myComponent", MyComponent );
    Vue.prototype.$myApi = api;
}
```

At the moment, the behavior I'm seeing is:

**GOOD**

- plugin `install` function is being executed
- functions from `api` attached to Vue.prototype are available in app components
- `my-component` is available in the app and renders markup

**BAD**

- `$myApi` and Vuetify components are **not** available in an application instance of of `my-component`

If I copy the same files into the app and change my import, all works as expected.  So, I now wonder if I'm missing something regarding sharing code via external modules.

I've tried these alternatives with the same issue:

- use `npm link` to link the plugin module to the app
- manually, use `mklink` (Windows sym link) to link plugin module to node_modules in the app folder
- use a long relative path reference to the plugin module: import MyPlugin from "../../../my-plugin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put this issue off for a while, but for anyone wondering, the issue is with using Single File Components and webpack not compiling those in external modules.

The 2 options I have are:

1. Don't use Single File Components. I.e.: Just use `.js` instead of `.vue`.  I've seen some libs like Vuetify.js take this approach
2. Compile the .vue files in the library module and include them in the source such as ./dist folder.